# how to use python help to file functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I want to see the `str.replace()` function: `help(str.replace)`
the result is:

```
Help on method_descriptor:

replace(...)
    S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> str

    Return a copy of S with all occurrences of substring
    old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
    given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
(END)
```

but how use help `file.read` or `readlines`?
for example, `help(file.read)` and `help(read)` are both errors:

```
>>> help(file)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
>>> help(file.read)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
>>> help(read)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'read' is not defined
```

How can I use help see file functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` type has been removed from Python 3. Look at the [`io` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) instead:

```
>>> import io
>>> help(io.TextIOBase.read)

Help on method_descriptor:

read(...)
    Read at most n characters from stream.

    Read from underlying buffer until we have n characters or we hit EOF.
    If n is negative or omitted, read until EOF.
```